# Latency & speed considerations between 2 servers on Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, database

I'm setting up a system that consists of:
2-4 database servers
2-4 webservers (running Node.js)

The webservers use the database servers heavily.
Aside from connecting to the private IPs of the database servers and using the same Availability Zone, how else can I increase the speed internally between these servers?

NOTE: This system might need to scale to 10X the size. I've used VPC before on a similar setup, but I'm not sure if that makes a difference in terms of internal speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VPC does not make any difference in latency.

The main thing you can consider if you need especially low latency is using [placement groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html). There are some limitations on which instance sizes support this, but if you use them, you are guaranteed very low-latency interconnects on the EC2 10Gbps network.